# SignalR .NET client works in console app but not in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, signalr

Here's my SignalR console app which works fine. It's able to receive messages from the Hub and print them onto the console.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MainAsync().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            hubProxy.On<string, string>("addMessage", (name, message) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incoming data: {0} {1}", name, message);
            });
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
            await hubConnection.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I created a windows service, and copied almost character for character, except the part where it prints to the console, I printed it to a log file

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            Log.Info("Starting...");
            StartListening().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
            IHubProxy hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            hubProxy.On<string, string>("addMessage", (name, message) =>
            {
                Log.Info(string.Format("Incoming data: {0} {1}", name, message));
            });
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
            await hubConnection.Start();
            Log.Info("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

Here's my server code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        string url = "http://*:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start(url))
        {
            MyHub hub = new MyHub();
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            var key = Console.ReadLine();
            while (key != "quit")
            {
                hub.Send("Server", key);
            }
        }
    }

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        //Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

However, nothing gets written to the log file except "Starting..." and "Connected"

There were no exceptions thrown either.

Do I need to include anything else or modify the code for SignalR to work on a windows service?

**Update**

Apparently, it seemed that changing this line

```
string url = "http://localhost:8080";
```

to this

```
string url = "http://*:8080";
```

in my server code solved my issue. But I don't know why.

Comment: Post the server-side code. Is your service running under the same account as your console app?

Comment: I have added my server code

Comment: It may not be *the* issue, but your `OnStart` code is wrong. `OnStart` is called on a thread that doesn't "belong" to you - it's wrong to block it with a `Wait` call. The Service Control manager doesn't consider your service to be started until you return from `OnStart`. If you want to have something running (or blocking) on a thread, you need to create one for yourself.

Comment: So how should my OnStart code be?

Comment: Typically you'd create your own threads and/or timers to do whatever work your service is meant to be doing and then return.

Comment: So all I need to do is to remove Wait() from my OnStart()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The problem was using `localhost` in the URL. Replace `localhost` with the actual server name.

The issue is explained [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1881253.aspx?More%20SelfHost%20Documentation).

> The URL is used to open an HttpListener. With the URL above (the
>   localhost one) this HttpListener will accept requests from 
>   `http://localhost` only. Other, equivalent URLs do not work:

```
http://127.0.0.1
http://110.120.130.140
http://myserver
```

Comment: Do take a look at my OP. I have updated it. It seems changing the code in my server worked.. but I'm not sure why

Comment: Isn't that what I said in my answer? You got rid of the word localhost.